# Is OnMouseUp()'s behavior intended?

Tags: c#, unity, events, callbacks

**Version:** Unity3D 4.6.2f1

I have a grid of tiles (Cube `GameObject`s with a `Tile` script attached). They are positioned at their index location `[x][y] = (x, y, z=0) World Coordinates`.

Below, I try to get the coordinates of the tile upon which the mouse left click is released.

Before into code:

> - [**`OnMouseDown()`**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) -  OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider.
> - [**`OnMouseUp()`**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html) - OnMouseUp is called when the user has released the mouse button.

Based on these definitions, *I assumed (mistake?) `OnMouseUp()` would be called by the object that above it, the mouse left click was released.*

On the `Tile` script, I have the following :

```
public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    // variables
    private Vector2 _gridPosition = Vector2.zero;

    public Vector2 GridPosition
    {
        get { return _gridPosition; }
        set { _gridPosition = value; }
    }

    // functions
    string Vec2toText(Vector2 v)
    {
        return String.Format("(" + v.x + ", " + v.y + ")");
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("TILE:: ON_MOUSE_DOWN:: " + Vec2toText(_gridPosition));
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Debug.Log("TILE:: ON_MOUSE_UP:: " + Vec2toText(_gridPosition));
    }

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        Debug.Log("TILE:: MOUSE_ENTER: " + Vec2toText(_gridPosition));
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("TILE:: MOUSE_EXIT: " + Vec2toText(_gridPosition));
    }
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqXZS.png) is the output:

```
TILE:: MOUSE_ENTER: (15, 15)
TILE:: MOUSE_DOWN: (15, 15)
TILE:: MOUSE_EXIT: (15, 15)
TILE:: MOUSE_ENTER: (14, 15)
TILE:: MOUSE_UP: (15, 15)    %% This line
TILE:: MOUSE_EXIT: (14, 15)
```

I would expect `OnMouseDown()` to be called by the object on which the mouse button was pressed (no problem here) and `OnMouseUp()` to be called by the object on which the mouse button was released (instead, it is called by the same object as `OnMouseDown()`).

Is this -- calling two functions by the same object even though I pressed left click some object and released it on some other object -- intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is, because otherwise an object which is clicked won't be able to determine when the mouse button is released again.

The best alternative I can think of is raycasting.

Put all objects which can possibly be in front of the tiles in the `Ignore Raycast` layer.
Then, from a "manager" script, cast a `Raycast` from the mouse cursor's position into the world, check which tile is being clicked, store the clicked `GameObject` in a variable `lastClicked`, and call some kind of method in its `Tile` script to tell that it was clicked, each update.
When the current hovered object is no longer equal to the `lastClicked` object, call some kind of method in the `Tile` script to tell that tje tile is no longer clicked.

Just ask me if you want a code example!

Best regards
*TheDDestroyer12*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Code example won't be necessary, I managed it with a static state variable and OnMouseXXX() calls.

Comment: @Varaquilex No problems! By the way, you might want to consider asking questions like this on Unity's own answers hub, which may give you more detailed answers.